# Instalacion de paquete local con pip3 no se detecta

Tags: python-3.x, pip, kali-linux

Instalo mi paquete con `pip3 install mi-paquete`, pero al hacer desde el terminal `$ mi-paquete` me da el error:

> error: command not found

Estoy trabajando con Kali.

> python3-pip ya está en su versión más reciente (20.3.4-4).
> 0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 1500 no actualizados.

Comment: reinicia la pc... y valida que pip3 esta instalado y que el servicio este ejecutandoce

Comment: Reinicie, pip3 esta instalado, como reviso que el servicio se este ejecutando?.

Comment: ejecuta: `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`

Comment: Ya esta instalado

Comment: ni idea entonces... algo hiciste que no has dicho...

Comment: posiblemente algo hice, pero no se que.

Answer (score 0):

Yo siempre prefiero usar `python -m pip install paquete-nuevo` y depaso me aseguro de usar python/python3/entorno que corresponde y no instalar en cualquier parte que el sistema diga que es el python por defecto.

[Post interesante relacionado](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/).